# Adding New Nodes in Modified Preorder Tree Traversal - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, modified-preorder-tree-t

I am having a postgresql table of approx 1500 rows and the model is “Modified Preorder Tree Traversal” structure based on Left and Right field.
and i want to insert many rows in between but i am not sure how to calculate the level, rightindex and leftindex columns values for multiple rows when inserting in between of rows.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US66L.png)

I believe for a single row we can do achieve this by below code,

```
SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM tablename

UPDATE tablename SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;

UPDATE tablename SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;


INSERT INTO tablename(name, lft, rgt)
    VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);
```

But how can we do this for multiple updates for a large table.

Please let me know if any further information is needed from my end.

Comment: First depending on where you want to add new nodes you should refer the node in the first select to get the insertion position (Pos). Then update existing nodes adding N*2 to lft, rgt of nodes after the Pos, where N = the number of new nodes. Finally insert new nodes , lft = i*2-1, rgt = i*2 where i=1..N . What part of the above is a problem?

Comment: Thank you Serg for the response,
The above code will work for adding one node but I was not sure how to achieve this for multiple nodes at once. 
Sorry, but can i write such code in postgresql ? and here N stands for the number of total nodes or the number of new nodes?
lft = i*2-1, rgt = i*2 where i=1..N .

Comment: N is the number of new nodes. Definitely Postgresql is quite capable tool for that. You can use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to get the set of numbers 1..N

Answer (score 0):

An example of a procedure which adds new items from the `NewNodes` table to the `tablename`

Setup

```
select * into tablename 
from(
  values
  ('gadgets',1,4, 1),
  ('games', 2,3, 2)
)t(name, lft, rgt, level);


select * into newNodes
from(
  values
  ('console'),
  ('cartridge')
)t(name);
```

The procedure adds new nodes after the node with the specified name at the same level.

```
create procedure addNodesFromNewNodes(posname varchar(10))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
declare
  pos int; lvl int;
  N int;
begin
  select rgt, level  into pos, lvl
  FROM tablename
  WHERE Name = posname;
  
  select count(*) into N
  from newNodes;
  
  update tablename 
  set lft = lft + 2*N
  where lft > pos;
  update tablename 
  set rgt = rgt + 2*N
  where rgt > pos;
  
  insert into tablename(name, lft, rgt, level)
  select t.Name, pos + 2 * rn - 1, pos + 2 * rn, lvl
  from (
     select Name, row_number() over(order by name) rn
     from NewNodes
  ) t;
end;
$$
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ad4b85b7f1261b3a2ff979ed546257b6)